# How to link Visual Studio Online with current Github repo

Tags: git, github, azure-devops

I am presently working with Github.

I just started to play with Visual Studio Online (VSO) and saw that I can use git.

Is there an easy way to link VSO and Github together?

I still want to use the Github interface, but would like to see what is happening from VSO (code change, issue resolved, etc)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Show this link. 
https://visualstudio.github.com/

Hoping it will be useful.

Comment: Wow, cool plugin and can be useful for other things that I have in my head! The thing is I am not using VisualStudio. Most of my work is done on Linux and sometimes I use Eclipse to edit my files. I push my changes with command line to Github. I want to use VSO for management. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Zapier](https://zapier.com/zapbook/visual-studio-online/) to integrate GitHub with Visual Studio Online.

Also take a look at this link for the details about using it: https://zapier.com/zapbook/updates/331/visual-studio-online-integrations/